# How does variable scope affect multithreading race conditions?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Are instance variables also shared just like static variables? Does this mean that race conditions happen due to static and instance variables only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes instance variables are shared as well, if multiple threads have access to the instance then there may be a need to protect against stale reads or multi-part writes that can corrupt the object's state.

Additionally, accessing external resources such as files on the file system can cause race conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't matter if the shared resource is a shared object, public instance variables or static content, all of these might cause [*race-condition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) (that is, unless the shared resource is [*immutable*](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29) ).

Answer (score 2):

instance variables of Runnable/Thread object are shared among threads (if multiple threads working on same object) and order or sequence of thread execution is not guaranteed which may lead to inconsistent results.

Comment: I think you understood my comment considering the new version of your answer

Comment: Context is related to thread, so I didn't explicitly add those words.

Answer (score 2):

> Are instance variables also shared just like static variables?

No, they are per-object, whereas statics are per-class.  You should have no direct issues with data members of thread objects - like any other object, each instance gets its own vars.  Similarly, of course, stack-based auto vars.

To get into multithreaded problems with thread-object instance variables and instance members of objects created by thread objects on a per-thread basis, you have to try harder.   With statics, it happens naturally:)

> Does this mean that race conditions happen due to static and instance variables only?

If you try hard enough, you can screw up almost anything.

Answer (score 0):

Without specific constructs to create thread-local context, nothing which holds state is thread safe by default. It's not just the instances of Runnable, anything which the code can touch and fails to lock is a potential source for undefined behavior (not just race conditions, there are other unpredictable partial update results which will render your application state equally compromised).